# Minimum of a sum of nonnegative monomials

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, optimization

Let $c,d\in\mathbb R$ and $f:[c,d]\rightarrow\mathbb R$ such that

$$
f(x)=\sum^N_{i=1}\max(a_i+b_ix,0),\text{for}\  a_i,b_i\in\mathbb R, i=1,...,N
$$

How to find $x$ on a closed subset of $\mathbb R$ (i.e. $x\in[c,d]$) such that $f$ is minimized ?

i.e. How to determine 
$$
\min_{x\in[c,d]} f(x)=\min_{x\in[c,d]}\left (\sum^N_{i=1}\max(a_i+b_ix,0)\right ),\text{for}\  a_i,b_i\in\mathbb R, i=1,...,N
$$
?

- Is there a general way to do it ? or is it on a case-by-case ?
- In this case : Does $x$ need (at most) to belong to the frontier of $[c,d]$ i.e. $x\in\{c,d\}$ since they are monomials ?

Comment: Have you tried the classical derivative approach? I know that the function $g(x)=max(0,x)$ is not differentiable in 0 but it's not a really big problem (you can think that you're approximating it with a smooth function) ;)

Comment: $\max(a_i+b_i\,x,0)$ is also for $x\in[c,d]$?

Comment: @JuliánAguirre yes

Comment: Regarding your second question, $x$ need not belong to the boundary. For example consider optimizing $|x| = \max(x,0) + \max(-x, 0)$ over the interval $[-1,1]$.

To add to Riccardo's suggestion, I would take a look at the softmax function: $f(x) = \log(\exp(kx) + 1) / k$ where $k$ is some large number you pick.

Comment: @the-owner did you appreciate any of the answers?

Comment: @LinAlg I really appreciate your answers thank you a lot for the time you have granted to answer me !!!!! However I think I have found another simpler way to solve the problem (far less complex) I will write the proof when I will get time :)

Comment: @the-owner that would be nice, maybe just outline a sketch of your method for now

Answer (score 2):

Your function is convex. A simple method is bisection search. Start with the interval $[c,d]$, consider the midpoint $m=(c+d)/2)$ and compute the subdifferential at $m$. The subdifferential is an interval $[l,u]$ where
$$
l = \sum_{i : a_i+b_ix > 0 } b_i  \\
u = \sum_{i : a_i+b_ix \geq 0} b_i 
$$
if 0 is in the subdifferential, you have found the optimum. If $u < 0$, the optimum is to the right of $m$, so you continue on the interval $[m,d]$. Otherwise, you continue on $[c,m]$. Repeat the procedure until the interval is sufficiently small.

Answer (score 2):

In the case, the numerical approach suffices, you can formulate the problem as a convex-concave saddle point problem.

First, notice that $\max(t, 0) = \max_{u\in [0,1]} ut$. With this, you can rewrite the  problem as

$$
\min_{x\in [c,d]}\max_{y\in [0,1]^N} \langle Bx,y\rangle + \langle a,y\rangle,
$$
where $a = (a_1,\dots, a_N)$ and $Bx = (b_1x,\dots, b_Nx)$.

Now you can apply any method suitable for solving saddle point problems (the primal-dual hybrid gradient, ADMM, variational inequalities methods, etc.)

Here is how iterations generated by the primal-dual hybrid gradient will look like:
\begin{align*}
x^{k+1} & = P_{[c,d]}(x^k - \tau B^Ty^k)\\
y^{k+1} & = P_{[0,1]^N}(y^k + \sigma (B(2x^{k+1}-x^k)+a)),
\end{align*}
where $x^0\in [c,d]$, $y^0\in [0,1]^N$, and steps $\tau>0$, $\sigma >0$ satisfy $\tau \sigma < \frac{1}{\|B\|_2^2} = \frac{1}{b_1^2+\dots b_N^2}$.

Note that the original problem was non-smooth, hence direct methods (e.g. subgradient ones) would not be efficient.